# Convert time to fractional second

Tags: r, time

I have a variable which is a list of time

```
t <- c("00:01:09.25", "00:01:25.24")
```

I want to convert them to fractional second so that it's numeric and I can do correlation between t and another variable. If convert t to a POXITlc object, I can do subtraction or other operations on t, but if I correlate a POXITlc object with a continuous variable, error pops up: x is not a numeric vector.

That's why I want to convert t into fractional second:
00:01:09.25 = 01 * 60 * 100 + 09* 100 + 25 = 6925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function strsplit to split based on ":"

```
x<-"00:01:09.25"
y<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,":")))
y[1]*60*60*100+y[2]*60*100+y[3]*100 #desired output
```

Use lapply to apply this on a vector of strings:

```
t <- c("00:01:09.25", "00:01:25.24")
unlist(lapply(strsplit(t,":"), function(x) as.numeric(x[1])*60*60*100+
as.numeric(x[2])*60*100+as.numeric(x[3])*100))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
100*period_to_seconds(hms(t))
#[1] 6925 8524
```